# Number of points in fibre of local diffeomorphism is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let
$$f : M \to N$$
be a surjective local diffeomorphism between connected smooth manifolds.
In particular, every $q \in N$ is a regular value, so $f^{-1}(q)$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$ of dimension $0$, i.e. a discrete set. Suppose that $f^{-1}(q)$ is actually finite for all $q \in N$.

**Question.** Is it true that the number of elements of $f^{-1}(q)$ is constant, i.e. independent of $q$?

My intuition is that if $|f^{-1}(q)|$ drops at some point then we have a singularity in $M$, but I'm having trouble making that rigorous.

Comment: Hint: Consider the inclusion map $(0,1)\to (0,2)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What do you mean by $(0, 1) \to (0, 2)$?

Comment: This is a standard notation for functions and maps, in this case, $M=(0,1), N=(0,2)$. How is it unclear?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Okay, sorry. For some reason, it didn't occur to me that $(0, 1)$ denotes an open interval here. Note, however, that I require $f$ to be surjective. (I forgot this initially, but I edited the question shortly after.)

Comment: Ok, then take $\exp(it)$ restricted to $(0, 4\pi)$.

Comment: **HINT**: There's a reason that degree of a smooth map is only defined when $M$ is compact (or $f$ proper).