# Local diffeomorphism is injective on connected components of preimage of neighborhood

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be connected smooth manifolds and
$$ f : M \to N$$
a surjective local diffeomorphism with finite fibres.

**Question.** Does every $q \in N$ have a neighborhood $U$ such that the restriction of $f$ to each connected component of $f^{-1}(U)$ is injective?

Note that this is true if $f$ is a covering map, but we can't assume this. The issue is that the number of points in a fibre can jump. [For example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4517329/1088679), we can consider
$$ f : (0, 3\pi) \to S^1, \quad f(\theta) = e^{i\theta}.$$
This is not a covering map, but still satisfies the property of the question.

Comment: $f$ is a local diffeomorphism so we can pick a neighborhood of $q$ and $p\in f^{-1}(q)$ which are homeomorphic via $f$. Now shrink the neighborhood of $q$.

Comment: @onepotatotwopotato The issue is that the preimage of a neighborhood of $q$ may have connected components which don't intersect $f^{-1}(q)$. It is not clear to me how to ensure that $f$ is injective on the components not intersecting $f^{-1}(q)$.